# My angular 2 page takes huge load time to load

Tags: angular

I am currently setting up a new project in angular 2 and I only have a single page. And that page too only has static HTML in it.
The total size of files transferred is only 25KB which is downloaded in about 800ms but after that also my page keeps on loading and it took more than 30secs to load.
Please advice.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNpPv.png)

Comment: try to use this command `ng build --prod --aot` which is probaly reduce your time upto 5 to 6 seconds

Comment: I am already using webpack. I can see that all files are downloaded too within a second. But still page keep on loading.

Comment: Could you host it somewhere like Surge or something so that we can debug as well?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, It's a static page and it is just a multistep form. Loading time is quite higher. I think it should not exceed 4-6 seconds.